# PHP Sqlite Configuration in Windows Not Working

Tags: php, sqlite, configuration

I am having difficulty getting PHP(5) on Windows to work with Sqlite.  After some research, I found that I have to change the <kbd>php.ini</kbd> file so that it reads (without semi-colons):

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_sqlite.dll
```

I ran the `phpinfo()` command, and verified that my computer is reading the right <kbd>php.ini</kbd> file.  Additionally, I have both <kbd>php_sqlite.dll</kbd> and <kbd>php_pdo_sqlite.dll</kbd> located in an ext file located in the folder with the php.ini file.  However, `phpinfo` indicates that the PDO drivers are *"no value"*, and there is no indication of *sqlite* anywhere.

I am now stuck, because all of my resources state that the above should work.  I noticed that my php.ini file has the following: `extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll` and `extension=php_sqlite.dll`.  The "extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll" is different from "extension=php_pdo.dll" in my above example.  I tried removing the extension and adding "extension=php_pdo.dll", but that did not make a difference.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Thank you,

DFM

Comment: @DFM: if you turn the to E_ALL `error_reporting(E_ALL)` you don't get any error, no error also in the apache log file ?

Comment: Hello RageZ, I am actually using an IDE (phpDesigner7) to test the PHP connection to Sqlite.  Before I run any code, shouldn't I see PDO and Sqlite enabled within the phpinfo first?

Answer (score 0):

As a resolution to this issue, I ended up installing WAMP and using a basic editor, instead of the IDE.  The php.ini file was already configured so connecting to Sqlite was pretty much straight forward.

Thanks,

DFM